# Why is my code not printing proper result when I am using requestDispatcher.forward function?

Tags: java, html, servlets, forward, requestdispatcher

I am trying to learn the `requestDispatcher.forward` function. So I wrote an Html code and then as we click the submit button on the HTML page it goes to a webservlet1. There I use forward function to go to webservlet2.

Please see the code below

`web.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
div{
    top:10px;
    left:100px;
    width:250px;
    height:120px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-color:green;
    background-color:yellow;
    
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loginValidation(){
    var FirstName=document.LoginForm.fname.value;
    var LastName=document.LoginForm.lname.value;
    if(FirstName=="" || LastName=""){
        alert("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form name="LoginForm" action="welcomeservlet1" onsubmit="return loginValidation()" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" name="lname"/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="login"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for `welcomeservlet1`

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
            String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
            String FullName=fname+" "+lname;
            FullName=FullName.toUpperCase();
            out.println("<h1><font color=green> Welcome "+FullName+"</font></h1>\n");
            request.setAttribute("Fullname",FullName);
            RequestDispatcher requestdispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcomeservlet2");
            requestdispatcher.forward(request, response);
            out.println("<br>Thank you");
        }
    
    }
```

Code for `WelcomeServlet2`

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Name=request.getAttribute("Fullname").toString();
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("Your full name is "+Name+"\n");
            out.println("<br>The name length is "+Name.length());
        }
```

The output of the code is

Your full name is Muskan AGARWAL
The name length is 12

Why is the code not printing what I am putting in the `welcomeservlet1` code? It is not printing "Welcome Muskan Agarwal". Why is it not printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the servlet specification, `forward` should be called only if no output has been committed to the client. If you try to `forward` when the output has already been committed to the client, the `IllegalStateException` will be thrown.

## Why did you not face `IllegalStateException`?

You did not face this exception because the output has not been committed in your code. If you put `response.flushBuffer();` before `requestdispatcher.forward(request, response);`, you will face this exception.

## And finally...why did "Welcome ..." not get printed?

It is because any uncommitted output was simply thrown away before `forward`.

Comment: Thank you Arvind for the answer.